# find matching combination of values between multiple data frame? r

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to subset matching combination of values from multiple data frames in r.

my first data set looks like this

```
head(df_1)
  BCluster ACluster Total_tim ttransfer
1        0        0      955.      1   
2        0       15     3060       0   
3        0       36     2433       1   
4        0       47     2518.      1.5 
5        0       51     1122.      0.15
6        0       67      750       1
```

my second data set looks like this

```
head(df_2)

  BCluster ACluster Total_tim ttransfer
1        5        5     1739.         0
2        5       11     2842          0
3        5       12     4661          0
4        5       27     2913          0
5        5       29     3748.         0
6        5       42     2035          0
```

third one looks like this

```
head(df_3)
  BCluster ACluster Total_tim ttransfer
1        0        0     6544          2
2        0       11     2834          1
3        0       15     2159          2
4        0       24     4658          1
5        0       29     5740.         1
6        0       31     2724          2
```

All three data sets are combinations of ID columns "Bcluster" and "ACluster".
For these three data frames, I would want to keep the overlapping combinations of Bcluster and Acluster
of each dataframe and remove the others

for example, since in df_2 there are no combinations of Bcluster=0 & Acluster=0. Bcluster=0 & Acluster=0 combinations appear only on the first rows of df_1 and df_3 so I would want them all removed from each dataframe.

I hope if anyone could help me code this logic.

sample data

```
 dput(head(df_1))
structure(list(BCluster = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ACluster = c(0L, 
15L, 36L, 47L, 51L, 67L), Total_tim = c(955.25, 3060, 2433, 2518.5, 
1122.4, 750), ttransfer = c(1, 0, 1, 1.5, 0.15, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(BCluster = 0L, .rows = structure(list(
    1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
dput(head(df_2))
structure(list(BCluster = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), ACluster = c(5L, 
11L, 12L, 27L, 29L, 42L), Total_tim = c(1739.31818181818, 2842, 
4661, 2913, 3748.33333333333, 2035), ttransfer = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(BCluster = 5L, 
    .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



> dput(head(df_3))
structure(list(BCluster = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ACluster = c(0L, 
11L, 15L, 24L, 29L, 31L), Total_tim = c(6544, 2834, 2159, 4658, 
5739.5, 2724), ttransfer = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(BCluster = 0L, .rows = structure(list(
    1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Can you share sample data using dput() function for 3 dataframes?

Comment: @KarthikS sure!! I have edited by question. Thanks

Comment: I solution I thought was to generate all combinations of Bcluster and Acluster. columns Bcluster and Acluster are just IDs of places. I have 47304 IDs so I could not generate combinations of 47304*47304. In fact each data frames do not use all the combinations.

Comment: So, in you sample data, nothing matches as you mentioned you need to match on both BCluster and ACluster, it may be difficult to see the output in that case.

Comment: @KarthikS it is quite a large dataframe i cannot add the data using dput() . They are each 4 by 199371, 299197,74052 respectively. Any suggestions? So my final output would probably be smaller than 74052*4 data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me construct some data to show

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,2,3), dat=c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,4,4), b=c(1,5,5), dat=c(4,5,6))
df3 <- data.frame(a=c(1,6,6), b=c(1,7,7), dat=c(7,8,9))
```

which gives you e.g.

```
> df1
  a b dat
1 1 1   1
2 2 2   2
3 3 3   3
```

key idea is now that you define a unique link key, say from columns `a` and `b`:

```
my.key <- function(x) paste(x, collapse='-')
df1$key <- apply(df1[,c('a','b')],1,FUN=my.key)
df2$key <- apply(df2[,c('a','b')],1,FUN=my.key)
df3$key <- apply(df3[,c('a','b')],1,FUN=my.key)
```

which gives you e.g.

```
> df1
  a b dat key
1 1 1   1 1-1
2 2 2   2 2-2
3 3 3   3 3-3
```

now you can join the data and keep only records, resp. keys, which uniquely match:

```
df <- data.frame(key=merge(merge(df1, df2, by='key'), df3, by='key')$key)
```

which now contains the keys of the records which are in all 3 data sets, which is only the first:

```
> df
  key
1 1-1
```

no you can use that new steering table as a device to filter on the original sets and return those records which are in the steering table and hence in all data sets:

```
merge(df1, df, by='key')
merge(df2, df, by='key')
merge(df3, df, by='key')
```

which yield

```
> merge(df1, df, by='key')
  key a b dat
1 1-1 1 1   1

> merge(df2, df, by='key')
  key a b dat
1 1-1 1 1   4

> merge(df3, df, by='key')
  key a b dat
1 1-1 1 1   7
```

Comment: wow thanks for the brief explanation thank you so much!!